# Stirling numbers second kind in vba

Tags: vba, excel, numbers

i created a code in VBA to calculate the amount of combinations for stirling numbers of second kind. But in following example only half of the values are correct.

---

The result should be 1,7,6,1 if n is equal to 4. ([Wikipedia stirling numbers](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling-Zahl)

I get 1,7,6.5,4.16

```
Sub stirlingerzahlen()
Dim n As Integer
Dim sum As Double
Dim subsum As Double
Dim k As Long
Dim j As Long
n = 4

For k = 1 To n Step 1
    For j = 0 To k Step 1
       subsum = 1 / Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(k) * (-1) ^ (k - j) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(k) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(j) * j ^ n
        sum = sum + subsum
    Next
    Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(k, 1) = sum
    sum = 0
Next
End Sub
```

Can someone find the mistake?

Comment: Your binomial coefficient calculation is incorrect. Also, with care, you can do this in integer arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not really into math or coding. I want to solve a logistics question. An approach how to continue or how to modify my code would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another version of the formula which seems to be easier to implement:

http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/junker/ss10/DAS-SS10.pdf
(Page 13)

[image]

And here the updated code:

```
Sub stirlingerzahlen()
Dim n As Integer
Dim sum As Double
Dim subsum As Double
Dim k As Long
Dim j As Long
n = 4

For k = 1 To n Step 1
    For j = 0 To k
        subsum = (((-1) ^ (k - j)) * ((j ^ n) / (Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(j) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(k - j))))
        sum = sum + subsum
    Next
    Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(k, 1) = sum
    sum = 0
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. Do you have any idea how to start the code if i want to calculate all the combinations and show them in excel. For example:  { a,b,c} {d };  { a,b,d} {c };  {a,b} {c,d} ?

Comment: Take a look at following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22128114/2507819 The paper of Michael Orlov describes how to write an algorithm for that. Also there is a link to a java class "SpecialPartitionGenerator" which does exactly what you need. Just try to understand it and then you can easily convert it to VBA. If you experience any problems just open a new question. PS: it would be nice if you flag my answer as "accepted" as it's working for you ;-)

Comment: Both of your answers helped me a lot. I will ask a new question how to Convert the C++ to VBA because I am not into this language.

Comment: Careful! The formula given above will give incorrect results if you try to implement it using integer (floor) division. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/46844/7133) for a formula that works using integer math. An equivalent formula is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition). (It's important to keep the k! divisor in those formulas outside of the sum.)